# line graph with irregular points - jquery

Tags: jquery, graph, charts, linechart

I want to make a line graph with irregular points.
I have a table where every bank account transaction gets logged. With this table i want to create a chart where the amount of money after a transaction gets displayed. So there could be multiple transactions in 1 minute but also no transactions for 2 weeks. I saw many jequery librarys which offer only charts with fixed points like every hour.
Is there an easy jquery that can do this?

here is am example of my table

```
userID   |    money   |    date
  1      |    2200    |    16.09.2014 19:38:25
  1      |    2500    |    16.09.2014 19:40:33
  1      |    1600    |    22.09.2014 07:16:22
```

Comment: it sounds like you want to be able to set custom, even variable, scales on the X/Y axes? not so much irregular points, but irregular scaling? i.e. instead of logging transactions per hour, where a few look good but many blend together if they are in the same minute, you want to be able to log transactions per hour if they are sparse, and per minute if there are many in a short span?

Comment: after some further searching i found this. but i cant get it running: http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/ytcW3/ this is how i imagined it.

Comment: that's a nice demo and you may find it easier to start from that example and build it into your own demo/production code. but, it seems like you want to be able to "zoom" the X axis by certain increments, in and out. if you can design your possible graph increments in your existing code, you can use jQuery to remove the chart and replace it with the zoomed version whenever the user clicks a Zoom +/- button. It's always hard to know whether or not to build from an example, or from scratch, but it's almost always hard to combine 2 code bases without some editing.

Comment: no thats a feature that i dont have to have :D I realy want only a chart where i can add a point on the time axis where ever i want. So this would be perfect but i cant get it running when i transfer it 1:1 over in my project. With this i have only to change my date format so i can use my values. but i cant get it to run.

Comment: I think i have found what i needed. I dont know where i found it. It was suddenly in one of my browser tabs :D  And the more important thing: I got it transfered in my project. Now i only have to insert the values from my table. http://jsfiddle.net/KnTaw/9/